# i want to solve the equations: x**2*y**2 + x**2 -10*x*y + 4*y**2 + 9.0=0,Is there any way to get the real solutions?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am trying to use python to solve the equations: `x**2*y**2 + x**2 -10*x*y + 4*y**2 + 9.0=0`, due to the equations equal to `(x*y-3)**2+(x-2*y)**2=0` ,so hoping to get the real solution: `x = 2*sqrt（3.0/2),y = sqrt(3.0/2)&& x = -2*sqrt（3.0/2),y = -sqrt(3.0/2)` Is there any way to get this solutions?

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
y = symbols("y")
expression = x**2*y**2 + x**2 - 10*x*y + 4*y**2 + 9
solve(expression,(x,y))
```

above code only get the solution: `[((5*y + I*(-2*y**2 + 3))/(y**2 + 1), y),
 ((5*y + I*(2*y**2 - 3))/(y**2 + 1), y)]`,thanks for your help and advice

Comment: You cannot solve a two-variable system with a single equation. Thus the output is the correct answer, it gives you a curve in the 2D space

Comment: The solutions you list are the only real solutions, but I don't know how to find those automatically. Analytically you can see that if you want the complex part of the solution to be 0, y has to be one of the roots of (2*y**2-3)==0..

Comment: One equation, two unknowns.  The best you can do is solve for one in terms of the other and plot the results over the range of the independent variable.  This is a math problem, not a coding issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is a lack of understanding of the mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you are trying to do is find where both of the terms of the expression `(x*y-3)**2+(x-2*y)**2` are simultaneously zero. Instead of expanding that, ask solve for that answer:

```
>>> eq = (x*y-3)**2+(x-2*y)**2
>>> terms = eq.args
>>> solve(terms, x, y)
[(-sqrt(6), -sqrt(6)/2), (sqrt(6), sqrt(6)/2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `solveset_real` (although the exact equation may not have any real solutions)

Comment: i used the solvest_real, but still can't get the real result:Intersection(Reals, {5*y/(y**2 + 1) - I*(2*y**2 - 3)/(y**2 + 1), 5*y/(y**2 + 1) + I*(2*y**2 - 3)/(y**2 + 1)})